# How to check one idle timeout in all tabs after user login in angular

Tags: angular, authentication, timeout

I need to check inactivity user after user login. User may work with the app in the different tabs. I implemented some solutions for this task, but every one has some issues.

1. Using idle-ng library: It is work only for one tab (I called it in login component), if I call it in app component it runs only one time and after log out, it doesn't run in login component.
2. using @hostlistener('click'): For example, when I call it in app component, it runs only in one tab and doesn't check in other tabs.

could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Local storage?

It's bound per-domain rather than per tab, so you could store your last activity timestamp in there.

`app.component` (presumably):

```
private readonly userActivityKey: string = 'user-activity';

@HostListener...

public ngOnInit(): void {
    setInterval(() => this.checkUserActivity(), 60000); // that's a minute, right?
}

public onClickEvent(): void {
    localStorage.setItem(this.userActivityKey, new Date());
}

private checkUserActivity(): void {
    const lastActiveDateTime = localStorage.getItem(this.userActivityKey);
    // check the time...
}
```

Each tab would update the local storage value whenever clicked, and all would read from that same place on their timers.

It's not so expensive to hit local storage that you can't have 50 tabs all hitting it every minute or so.